# How to create a custom Navigate function MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

Hi I am trying to create a custom Navigation function using `INavigationService`. I'm probably way off, but here's what I have in my `BaseViewModel`:

```
public async Task Navigate<T>(object type)
    {
        if (canNavigate)
        {
            canNavigate = false;
            if (type is T)
            {
                await _navigationService.Navigate<type>();
            }
            canNavigate = true;
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't work, but basically I am trying to pass my ViewModel class as a param so I can call it like so: `_navigationService.Navigate<VM type here>`.

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the reason for the type check here?

Comment: So I can see if the object passed is of the ViewModel type specified by <T>. Thought I had to pass the VM type as an object. Something like: `await Navigate<MyViewModel>(viewModel)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are trying to implement what is already in the API: `Task<bool> Navigate<TViewModel>(...) where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel;`.

To be sure the type of passed object is correct, just pass it with T type:

```
public async Task Navigate<T>(T object) where T : <yourTypeHere>
```

The other question is why do you need to object inside, if you have already needed type in T.

Comment: Thanks I implemented that function into an interface and then added that to my `BaseViewModel`. Now I can modify as needed